# Como mesclar imagens e texto para transformar em uma única foto?

Tags: javascript, html, css

alguém sabe me dizer como eu faço pra funcionar o botão pra salvar?
Eu quero colocar pra quando apertar o botão "salvar userbar", salvar em uma imagem todo o conteúdo que está na div "userbar".

Eu tentei usar o html2canvas mas na hora que tira a print,não aparecem as imagens que está dentro (apesar que eu fiz um teste colocando essas imagens no site do html2canvas,e no print saiu a imagem).

Me ajudem por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você pode ver no console, tem a ver com `cors`, tenta colocar as imagens no mesmo endereço que você está rodando a página.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nickname').click(function() {
    var $text = $(this),
      $input = $('<input class="input-nickname"type="text" />')

    $text.hide()
      .after($input);

    $input.val($text.html()).show().focus()
      .keypress(function(e) {
        var key = e.which
        if (key == 13) // enter key
        {
          $input.hide();
          $text.html($input.val())
            .show();
          return false;
        }
      })
      .focusout(function() {
        $input.hide();
        $text.show();
      })
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Salvar').click(() => {
    html2canvas($("#userbar"), {
        allowTaint: true,
        logging: true,
        taintTest: false,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
              saveAs(blob, "image.png");
            });
        }
    });
  });

  $('.nomeclan').click(function() {
    var $text = $(this),
      $input = $('<input class="input-nomeclan"type="text" />')

    $text.hide()
      .after($input);

    $input.val($text.html()).show().focus()
      .keypress(function(e) {
        var key = e.which
        if (key == 13) // enter key
        {
          $input.hide();
          $text.html($input.val())
            .show();
          return false;
        }
      })
      .focusout(function() {
        $input.hide();
        $text.show();
      })
  });
});
```

```css
.control-label .text-info { display:inline-block; }

#userbar {
    width: 500px;
    height: 99px;
    background-color:transparent;

}
.nomeclan {
    position: absolute;
    color: #96969a;
    font-size: 17pt;
    margin-left: 165px;
    margin-top: -84px;
    font-family: Quantico;
}

.nickname {
    position: absolute;
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 22pt;
    margin-left: 165px;
    margin-top: -83px;
    font-family: Quantico;

}
.patente {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -82px;
    width: 52px;
    margin-left: 103px;
}
.insignia {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-top: -102px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.marca {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -101px;
}

.fita {
    position: relative;
    height: 99px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: -3px;
}
.input-nickname {
    border: none;
    background-color: #00000047;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -77px;
    margin-left: 164px;
    height: 26px;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 29px;
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-family: Quantico;
    text-align: left;
}
.input-nomeclan {
    border: none;
    background-color: #00000000;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -82px;
    margin-left: 165px;
    height: 26px;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #96969a;
    font-family: Quantico;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quantico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://fastcdn.org/FileSaver.js/1.1.20151003/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="userbar">
    <img id="changefita"class="fita" src="http://wf.mail.ru/wiki/images/1/1a/Challenge_strip_ny.png">
    
        <img id="changeinsignia"class="insignia" src="http://wf.mail.ru/wiki/images/d/d1/Challenge_badge_ny.png">
        
    <img id="changemarca"class="marca" src="http://wf.mail.ru/wiki/images/6/6f/Challenge_mark_03.png">
    
    <img src="https://warface.uol.com.br/imagens/conteudo/guia-do-jogo/patentes/trainee.png" class="patente" id="changeptt">
    <span class="nomeclan">WarNight</span>
    <br>
    <br>
<span class="nickname">WarNight</span>



</div>

<button id="Salvar">Salvar userbar</button>


<select onchange="$('#changeptt').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="https://warface.uol.com.br/imagens/conteudo/guia-do-jogo/patentes/trainee.png" selected>Patente 1</option>
    <option value="https://warface.uol.com.br/imagens/conteudo/guia-do-jogo/patentes/cadete-junior.png">Patente 2</option>
    <option value="https://warface.uol.com.br/imagens/conteudo/guia-do-jogo/patentes/cadete.png">Patente 3</option>
</select>
  
<select onchange="$('#changefita').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="http://wf.mail.ru/wiki/images/1/1a/Challenge_strip_ny.png" selected>Fita 1</option>
    <option value="http://wf.mail.ru/wiki/images/7/7f/Challenge_strip_ww2.png">Fita 2</option>
    <option value="http://wf.mail.ru/wiki/images/5/54/Challenge_strip_01.png">Fita 3</option>
</select>

<select onchange="$('#changemarca').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="http://wf.mail.ru/wiki/images/6/6f/Challenge_mark_03.png" selected>Marca 1</option>
    <option value="https://wf.mail.ru/wiki/images/e/ef/Challenge_mark_04.png">Marca 2</option>
    <option value="https://wf.mail.ru/wiki/images/1/1a/Challenge_mark_05.png">Marca 3</option>
</select>

<select onchange="$('#changeinsignia').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="http://wf.mail.ru/wiki/images/d/d1/Challenge_badge_ny.png" selected>Marca 1</option>
    <option value="http://wf.mail.ru/wiki/images/6/69/Challenge_badge_ww2.png">Marca 2</option>
    <option value="http://wf.mail.ru/wiki/images/2/27/Challenge_badge_15.png">Marca 3</option>
</select>
<style>
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: mannnn, funcionou perfeitamente,muito obrigado :D já tava ficando triste achando q não ia funcionar.
kkk nem acredito :D vlw msm